# SQL-Missing comma error in insert into line

Tags: sql

```
BEGIN
FOR A IN (select passengerıd,name,sex from tıtanıc) LOOP
IF (A.sex='male') THEN
INSERT INTO man(personıd,name,gender) values(A.passengerıd,A.name,A.sex);
ELSE
INSERT INTO woman(personıd,name,gender) values(A.passengerıd,A.name,A.sex);
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

I am getting a "missing comma" error in the insert lines? Anyone can tell me why?

Comment: Please tag with the appropriate database engine / SQL dialect you're writing SQL for. There may be specific syntax variations that are in play here.

Comment: Actually its because i use variables from the select query. If i use regular variables it works fine even with funky ı characters.

Comment: Your sql query looks fine.

Comment: Curious why tables named *man* and *woman* would need a *gender* column?

Comment: More often than not, a LOOP is the wrong approach in SQL to do things. Plus: there are no loops or even an IF statement in standard SQL.  [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)